# Should [bootstrap-modal]'s description be changed?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that the tag [bootstrap-modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-modal) has a description that leads one to believe it's intended to be applied to questions concerning the [bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) project. The documentation links in the tag description, however, point to the [Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) section of the official Bootstrap documentation. Furthermore, randomly viewing a dozen or so questions with the [bootstrap-modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-modal), it would appear that the vast majority of questions with that tag are intended to reference the **official plugin**.

So, my question is this: should I (or someone with actual edit privileges) edit the description of the aforementioned tag to bring it inline with what seems to be the most common usage?

I realize I can just make the change, and let it get approved or rejected, but I would rather have a consensus on what would be a (relatively) major edit to this specific tag.

Comment: That's just poor naming by the author of that third party library, if it *"Extends the default Bootstrap Modal class"* it shouldn't be called *bootstrap-modal*.

Comment: @Stijn Agreed, and to be honest, it doesn't even look like what I would consider an active project, which is yet another reason to revise the tag wiki.